# Multiple sets of images to show on a single segue

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, imageview, callout

I am having a bit of trouble deciding how to approach this. I have a map app, where the pin annotations show a custom callout which is a segueway to a single screen. I want to have a set of images assigned to each pin so that on the screen the correct set of images are showing (as well as the other info I have on that one callout screen). Whether that be image view's or an image slideshow, I am unsure! Please any help would be greatly appreciated. This is for a high school project.

Comment: you can use pageviewController/collectionview/tableview with single imageView.if not can you explain clearly about your issue..

Comment: @Bapu i've figgured out a solution by using multiple image views, it serves what I want to do but thankyou for your help :)